# What is the best way to switch ViewController without using container viewControllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I want to switch the current view controller to another one, without using UINavigationController or UITabbarController. What is the best way to do this?

This is what I am doing in App Delegate code:

```
self.window.rootViewController = newViewController; //The one I am switching to
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Is there some more 'elegant' way?

== Edit ==

I guess what I need is a SwitchViewController, which clears the former view controller and replaces it with a new one, better with switching animations like fading out/in.

I think this is a valid question. Whoever down-votes it should at least add some comments to explain.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are many more options, if you don't want to present it as a modal view controller, or use the navigation stack, or on the other side using container view controllers or tab bar, the only thing I can think of it's changing the window.rootViewController as you said.

Have you thought about presenting view controllers without animation? Or using a hidden tab bar? You can select the tabs programatically.

Are you sure about not using them? I mean, any design can fit using those approaches, if you are an unexperienced developer I recommend you to re-think your approach.

Comment: The reason I don't want to use navigation/tabbar view controllers is that they don't satisfy my requirement. In my app, a series of view controllers could be loaded in no predefined pattern: A-B-C-D-B-A-C-..., and they are dynamically generated, so I don't want to keep formerly loaded VCs in memory. I don't need 'going back' in history, so I don't need a NavigationViewController; The viewcontrollers loaded are not known beforehand, so TabbarViewController is also not OK; besides, these 2 VCs keep the viewControllers in memory, I cannot afford this in my use case.

Comment: What about a tab bar hidden? You can benefit of the tabbar implementation and the user wont notice

Answer (score 0):

You can use segues without using a navigation controller - IMHO this is a little easier to follow than just reassigning the rootViewController.  I've created segues using Modal presentation - I'm not sure if Push would work without the nav controller.  I did this in some earlier experiments, as I'm also fairly new to ios development, and have since switched to using a navigation controller - it gives you more flexibility, more cleanly, for not a lot of extra overhead... As Antonio suggested, you may want to re-consider the use of a navigation controller.